# How to generate a zip with a dat file and a txt file with C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, download, zip

I need to create a file txt and a file with extension dat. After that I want to compress these files into a zip file and to download it.

My problem is that I don't want to save the files before download. So, can I create and download the zip without creating files on server?

Comment: I've used the [ZipFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx) class to zip things from c# before.

Comment: What you are after is called streaming support. Try [Nunrar](http://nunrar.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Stream%20Usage&referringTitle=Documentation) it does that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **MemoryStream**. Below you can find the code:

```
public ZipOutputStream CreateZip(MemoryStream memoryStreamControlFile, MemoryStream memoryStreamDataFile)
{
    using (var outputMemStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(baseOutputStream))
        {
            zipStream.SetLevel(3); // 0-9, 9 being the highest level of compression
            byte[] bytes = null;

            // .dat
            var nameFileData = CreateFileName("dat");
            var newEntry = new ZipEntry(nameFileData) { DateTime = DateTime.Now };

            zipStream.PutNextEntry(newEntry);

            bytes = memoryStreamDataFile.ToArray();

            var inStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            StreamUtils.Copy(inStream, zipStream, new byte[4096]);
            inStream.Close();
            zipStream.CloseEntry();

            // .suc

            var nameFileControl = CreateFileName("suc");
            newEntry = new ZipEntry(nameFileControl) { DateTime = DateTime.Now };

            zipStream.PutNextEntry(newEntry);

            bytes = memoryStreamControlFile.ToArray();

            inStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            StreamUtils.Copy(inStream, zipStream, new byte[4096]);
            inStream.Close();
            zipStream.CloseEntry();

            // .zip

            zipStream.IsStreamOwner = false;
            zipStream.Close();

            outputMemStream.Position = 0;

            return zipStream;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are working with ASP.Net ?

You can put the file contents (stream, etc...) in a byte array, then output that directly to the user in the response, like :

```
string fileType = "...zip...";
byte[] fileContent = <your file content> as byte[];
int fileSize = 1000;
string fileName = "filename.zip";

Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
Response.ContentType = fileType;
Response.OutputStream.Write(fileContent, 0, fileSize);
```

Comment: Does setting the file extension to "zip" make the file compressed?!!

Comment: Of course not, I just provided the way to stream the "final file", assuming the OP would have already zipped it.